# Why is there an HTMLAudioElement and a seperate Audio class?

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, web-audio-api

What are the difference between the two?

According to [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement) I create a new HTMLAudioElement by doing:

```
var audio = new Audio();
```

How is that different than the object I get from calling  `document.createElement('audio')`?

Is one of these more future proof than the other? In which cases should I choose one over the other?

Comment: What browser are you using? I'm getting all of the standard DOM methods on Chrome.

Comment: hmm, you're right, the DOM methods are there...editing my question...

Comment: they should be the same. a few tags have dedicated constructors above and beyond the `HTMLSomethingElement` and `document.createElement`. notably `Image`, `Audio`, and `Option`, maybe more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[According to the spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#the-audio-element) (and the MDN article you linked to) the `new Audio()` constructor simply creates an `HTMLAudioElement`. [Document.createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) creates an `HTMLxElement`, so they are equivalent. Browsers implement the full spec so [they aren't concerned](http://caniuse.com/#feat=audio).

`new Audio()` has the advantage of being arguably more declarative (you aren't necessarily concerned with its ties to the DOM). On the other hand, there's no `new Video()`, so for consistency you might find it helpful to use `createElement`.

Comment: indeed, its looks like `Object.getPrototypeOf(new Audio)` and `Object.getPrototypeOf(document.createElement('audio'))` both return `HTMLAudioElement` in Chrome